# Right-click on Big Sur

Tags: software-recommendation

The right click/secondary click can no longer be called by clicking on the bottom right of the trackpad in Big Sur. You have to Ctrl-click or two-finger click instead. I have too much muscle memory invested in the old way of doing things.

Is there a utility that will restore this functionality?

Comment: I wonder if you have a hardware failure or need to reinstall the OS. I see no removal of this setting but maybe there’s different hardware / some other config where we this is repeatable or expected?

Comment: Battery swelling causes all sorts of trackpad anomalies and would be amongst one of the first things to check (if it's a notebook)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No issue on my version of Big Sur (11.6)

System preferences shows it as an option to be chosen:

[image]